# Objective C, UITabBar EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, exc-bad-access

I have UITabBar which has 5 menus. Third menu downloads an image from my web server and shows the image in the UIImageView.

The problem is that whenever if I try to go back to the first menu after download the image then it blows up...The stack trace looks like this

```
 obj_msgSend
 ??
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:]
 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperView:]
```

If I comment the code that gets the image from server out then it works fine..
What might be the problem here?

Comment: Isn't this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280763/objective-c-tabbar-blows-up) related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, try to post code for downloading image that creates crash. EXEC_BAD_ACCESS happens usually when you try accessing variable that you have already released.